# Execute a before/after each in a specified should block out of many in Specs2

Tags: scala, specs2

I have a spec like the following written:

```
class MySpec extends Specification {

  "A" should {
    "be true" in {
      true must beEqualTo(true)
    }
  }

  "B" should {
    "be false" in {
      false must beEqualTo(false)
    } 
  }
  ...
}
```

How do I/Can I specify a before/after statement to execute only within the `"B"` block (for instance) for *each* test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a context for your test:

```
trait Context extends BeforeAfter {
  def before: Any = println("Doing setup")
  def after: Any = println("Done. Cleanup")
}

"B" should {
  "be false" in new Context  {
    false must beEqualTo(false)
   }
}
```

You can have a look at [this link](http://blog.scalac.io/2015/03/27/specs2-notes.html) if you need to do some tricky things with specs2.